# How to get bigger photos' thumbnails in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, photo-management, thumbnails, previews

Today I wanted to go through my photos collection but I have realised that it is quite difficult to go through thumbnails in Nautilus as it is using the free space in the window very inefficiently, e.g.

[image]

Is there any other option to use it less "padding" , free space between other photos ? Or should I use other window manager to achieve this ?

Comment: If you're still looking for bigger thumbnails, you may be interested in this answer I gave : https://askubuntu.com/a/1459134/607630

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Nautilus you can right click on a empty area in the folder and select **Zoom In** or use **Ctrl + Mouse scroll wheel** to zoom the pictures.

Alternate is to use **Thunar**

Comment: I already know about **Ctrl + Mouse scroll** but the more I zoom the bigger are the distances ( free space between ) the images :/ I will try Thunar  later when I am at home.

Comment: This is NOT a solution in 2020 because Nautilus now has reduced the maximum zoom. It's a design BUG or a BUG.

Answer (score 1):

I have ended up using `nemo` as file manager. There has been a new version recently on webupd8
http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/install-nemo-with-unity-patches-and.html

Answer (score 0):

The Control+ (Control key and Plus) and Control- (Control key and dash) should increase/decrease the icon's size, which should be permanent in every folder. This can also be done by pressing the Control key and mouse wheel.

This allow you to have different size icons in each folder as needed.

Additionally you can use the "Arrange Items/Compact Layout" in the context menu (right click) in order to use the folder's space (the right side pane's space) more efficiently.

Good luck!

Comment: I can't find the "Arrange Items/Compact Layout" options. On which version of Nautilius you can see see this ?

Comment: It seems they removed this tool starting from 12.04, may be before in an update for Nautilus. Sorry. See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/97606/missing-nautilus-option-compact-layout