# Larger thumbnails for pictures in nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I am trying to browse through a folder of screenshots I'd like the thumbnails to be bigger

In nautilus there is an option to zoom in to 133% but this isn't really big enough still, and appears to be the max level

Are there any recommendations here, or external programs I should use?

I am using Files 3.38.1-stable on Ubuntu 20.10 https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Files

[image: nautilus screenshot of thumbnails]

Comment: You don't mention which version of Nautilus you are using (nor which version of Ubuntu) but what option are you using to increase the zoom level. Please [edit] you question acordingly. Are you using Ctrl+ and Ctrl- to do this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for checking me on that. I added that I am using "Files" 3.38.1-stable. The Ctrl+ does perform this 133% zoom in (but you can also click the `\/` triangle drop down in menu bar to get there)

Comment: In [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/382248/307670) to a similar question, there was a suggestion about using nemo instead of nautilus.

Comment: just tested out nemo and it does do a bit better. even nemo has a maximum size that it can zoom to but it is about twice as large as what nautilus has

Comment: does that answer the question for you then?

Comment: @User24601 That does not answer the question, but may provide a workaround. The answer to this question indeed may be that it simply is not possible. It used to be possible by changing some gsettings (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1097934/nautilus-show-image-thumbnails-at-more-than-200-size, 2nd answer, but that way is not applicable anymore for the current version.

Comment: You may be interested in my answwer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/723732/220711