# What are my options to replace Gnome 3's Nautilus in the least intrusive way?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, nautilus, thumbnails, alternative

I use stock Ubuntu 20.04.2 with the Gnome 3.36.8 desktop (according to gnome-control-center's *About* tab).

Nautilus version: 3.36.3

**Dismay:**

I have a hard time **organizing my photos** in Nautilus, because the largest possible image thumbnail setting results in **thumbnails displayed at an effective 164px width**. (All the while the actual thumbnail .png files, in `~/.cache/thumbnails/large/`, are still being saved with the more sensible, earlier default 256px width. Yet someone decided that at display time, they need to be shrinked to 164px.)

I have found questions about enlarging Nautilus thumbnails:

- [How to get bigger photos' thumbnails in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/q/181479/1157519)

  - recommends using alternative file manager
- [Nautilus: Show image thumbnails at more than 200% size](https://askubuntu.com/q/1097934/1157519)

  - the [gsettings way](https://askubuntu.com/a/1097952/1157519) does not work any more

    - there is no `org.gnome.nautilus.icon-view thumbnail-size` any more
    - even if it doesn't appear, [probably it's set to 256px anyways](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/blob/gnome-3-36/src/nautilus-enums.h#L37), that's why actual thumbnail .png's in `~/.cache` are that wide; the resizing happens on the frontend, at display time
  - also recommends switching to alternate desktop

**My use-case:**

- Right now I'm not ready to switch desktops / to reinstall.

  - I have already invested 3 months of my life into making my Gnome desktop usable, at a very critical part of my life where I desperately should be focusing on other (real-life) challenges already.
- I have only 19GB left on my `/` partition, I would be happy if I would not need to fill it up to the brim.

While I use Gthumb, I find it less than optimal for file-manager-related tasks (moving files about); at the same time I don't want to use Shotwell, because it's very inflexible (thanks to its "import" procedure).

The recommended alternative file managers all seem to pull in their entire corresponding desktops:

- Caja: MATE desktop
- Nemo: Cinnamon desktop
- Thunar: XFCE desktop

This seems to be a huge overhead and therefore an inefficient solution.

**Question:**

Is there an efficient way for me to enjoy 256px wide thumbnails in a decent file manager with a decent image viewer app integration?

(If you are going to suggest building Nautilus from source, I will need an ELI5 walkaround of that, because I have never in my life built anything from source.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@ArchismanPanigrahi's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1332063/1157519) in which he revealed that those desktop-looking packages are not actually representing and not installing the entire desktops, I felt emboldened to install both *Nemo* and *Thunar*, together with their recommended packages.

`sudo apt install nemo` needed only ~30MB disk space, and

`sudo apt install thunar` needed only ~12MB disk space.

After a full reboot, on the purple GDM login screen, in the small cogwheel icon, no additional *Cinnamon deskop* or *XFCE desktop* option had shown up. (It still lists only *gnome-classic*, *Ubuntu*, and *Ubuntu on Wayland*)

Of course, I started to use both file managers with 256px thumbnails.

---

## Nemo

**Good stuff about Nemo:**

- "everything" can be configured, and more (there is heaps of stuff in `gsettings`)
- works in a sensible way, remembers which specific directories were viewed in list and which ones in thumbnail view modes and applies that view mode automatically; same goes for sorting

  - subdirectories can inherit their viewmode from their parents (excellent feature, makes things easy)

**Less good stuff about Nemo:**

- has a bit of un-handsome looks, especially in list view

  - it uses monochrome Adwaita icons in the sidebar
- tends to develop a very bad UI lag after some time (with i915 integrated graphics)

  - it seems to set itself up for difficulties when it tries to retrieve directory file counts anew upon every step of navigation
  - the UI lag can go so far as impacting the entire gnome-shell, pretty badly
  - as far as I can tell, the UI lag can be mitigated to some decent extent by disabling the file-count displays under directories

## Thunar

**Good stuff about Thunar:**

- even though the visual elements seem pretty similar, it has a more harmonic appearance than Nemo

  - it uses color icons in the sidebar
- through lack of decorations, it offers a very good overview of thumbnails
- remains snappy, no UI lags

**Less good stuff about Thunar:**

- the preferences dialog contains only a handful of settings, and there is nothing in `gsettings`
- the set view mode (list vs thumbnails) and sorting order applies to every directory visited thereafter; unlike Nemo, it does not try to restore the last used settings for specific directories
- it has a strange bug where some apparently random subset of the thumbnails (mixed in the same directory) shows up smaller than the rest (impacts .jpg's and .pdf's)

  - the fix seems to be easy: Thunar's "Tumbler" thumbnailing process seems to have two redundant thumbnailer plugins, resulting in race-conditions; [the fix is disabling one of these plugins](https://askubuntu.com/a/1340208/1157519).

Answer (score 6):

You can install `nemo` and `thunar` without their recommended packages. This won't pull Cinnamon desktop or the XFCE desktop.

```
sudo apt --no-install-recommends install nemo
```

Similarly for thunar

```
sudo apt --no-install-recommends install thunar
```

`caja` seems to install mate-desktop even with `--no-install-recommends`.

Nautilus used to have many more features back in 2010 (when GNOME 2 was still around), after which they began to [remove useful features](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/8jku75/gnome_is_removing_the_ability_to_launch_apps_from/) in the name of simplicity.

Comment: I used `apt install`'s `-s` (simulate) argument to investigate. In case of `nemo`, `--no-install-recommends` leaves away the following packages: `cinnamon-l10n gist hddtemp hwdata inxi nemo-fileroller tree` What still gets installed however is: `cinnamon-desktop-data libcinnamon-desktop4 libgail-3-0 libnemo-extension1 libxapp1 nemo-data xapps-common`

Comment: In case of `thunar`, `--no-install-recommends` leaves away: `libtumbler-1-0 libxfce4panel-2.0-4 libxfce4util-bin thunar-volman tumbler tumbler-common` (ironically, the thumbnailer!), but still installs: `exo-utils libexo-2-0 libexo-common libexo-helpers libthunarx-3-0 libxfce4ui-2-0 libxfce4ui-common libxfce4util-common libxfce4util7 libxfconf-0-3 thunar-data xfconf`

Comment: @Levente `cinnamon-desktop-data` or  `libcinnamon-desktop4` are not the full cinnamon-desktop. `sudo apt --no-install-recommends install nemo` is only a 1.7 MB download in my Kubuntu. The download size for `thunar` is also 1.7 MB, which means it won't bloat the GNOME desktop.

Comment: Seeing that in case of `nemo`, the install with recommended elements would be only `30MB`, while with `--no-install-recommends` it would be `7MB`, I went with installing _with_ the recommended stuff. Can it bite me in the future? Do you think it could download the full Cinnamon desktop _retroactively_ one day?

Comment: @Levente Most software in the repository receive only security updates (and minor updates), I doubt that a file manager would receive a huge enough update that would change its dependency structure. I don't have a Ubuntu VM right now. It would be interesting to know whether installing the recommended packages does install the full cinnamon DE.

Comment: I ended up doing `sudo apt install nemo`, so it came _with_ the recommended stuff, and it was only 30MB. And even after a full reboot, on the purple GDM login screen, in the small cogwheel icon, no additional "Cinnamon deskop" option shown up. (It still lists only gnome-classic, Ubuntu, and Ubuntu on Wayland). Your guidance was essential, pointing out that `libcinnamon-desktop4` is not the entire desktop. Thank you!